# Excel group "box with whiskers" chart by time

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics, pivot-chart

I am logging various data every five minutes from my broadband modem to learn how my devices behave over time.  This results in a lot of data I would like to use Excel to analyze.

[image: excel screen shot of sample data]

One piece of data is the signal strength which varies a bit between samples (please see image of data subset).  I've managed to create a pivot graph for these showing the average of the strength for each hour for each mac address, but I would like to have the additional statistical information provided by the Box with Whiskers chart type which works on the whole data set without subgrouping the timestamp so I can see the development in the statistics over time (probably around a month or so).

I am new to Excel and this is not something easily found in the tutorials, so pointers to good tutorial material will also be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've already been through https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-box-and-whisker-chart-62f4219f-db4b-4754-aca8-4743f6190f0d ?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes.  Have I missed a grouping option on date somewhere?